# How do I export RTF file using ruby-rtf in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have gone through the documentation of '[ruby-rtf](https://github.com/clbustos/rtf)'.

It is not very clear to me how to integrate this with my controller. I have done the following:

1. `gem install ruby-rtf`
2. insert into config/initializers/mime_types.rb

   ```
    Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
   ```
3. My view has an export button that routes to the following controller action. Here is my controller file:

   ```
   def export_file

       document = RTF::Document.new(RTF::Font.new(RTF::Font::ROMAN, 'Times New Roman'))
       document.paragraph do |p|
          p << "This is the first sentence in the paragraph. "
          p << "This is the second sentence in the paragraph. "
          p << "And this is the third sentence in the paragraph."
       end
       send_file document, :type=>"text/richtext"
   end
   ```

I get the following error, what am I doing wrong?

```
uninitialized constant JobVacanciesController::RTF
```

Comment: Did you add the gem to your Gemfile ? Maybe it also needs a `require 'RTF'` at the very top of the controller.

Comment: I had added to the Gemfile : gem 'ruby-rtf' , I added the require'RTF' to the controller and I get the following error: cannot load such file -- RTF

Answer (score 1):

The instructions above are correct, I had made a mistake in the gem installation.

The Gem needs to be

```
gem 'rtf'
```

and the controller needs line

```
require 'rtf'
```